# Can the Catholic Church err on particular grounds for an annulment in a marriage?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, annulment

In session 24 of the Council of Trent, Canon IV, the Church teaches that "If any one saith, that the Church could not establish impediments dissolving marriage; or that she has erred in establishing them; let him be anathema."

Is this declaration held by the Church to mean indefectability in all canonical proceedings of annulments granted or witheld by the Church? Or has it asserted rather that the Church in the principle of the matter **can** hold impediments to annullment of marriages but may err in any given case? That is to say that the Church can be mistaken on the grounds for annullment in any particular case, but the parties are bound to follow the decision of the Church?

This would be a religious analogue to the understanding that secular courts may err in the findings of a guilty or non-guilty verdict.

How has the Church shown the meaning of this canon?

> **Doctrine on the Sacrament of Matrimony**
>
> **Doctrine and Canons**
>
> Being the eighth under the Sovereign Pontiff, Pius IV., celebrated on the eleventh day of November, MDLXIII.

> The first parent of the human race, under the influence of the divine Spirit, pronounced the bond of matrimony perpetual and indissoluble, when he said; This now is bone of my bones, and flesh of my flesh. Wherefore a man shall leave father and mother, and shall cleave to his wife, and they shall be two in one flesh. But, that by this bond two only are united and joined together, our Lord taught more plainly, when rehearsing those last words as having been uttered by God, He said, therefore now they are not two, but one flesh; and straightway confirmed the firmness of that tie, proclaimed so long before by Adam, by these words; What therefore God hath joined together, let no man put asunder. But, the grace which might perfect that natural love, and confirm that indissoluble union, and sanctify the married, Christ Himself, the institutor and perfecter of the venerable sacraments, merited for us by His passion; as the Apostle Paul intimates, saying: Husbands love your wives, as Christ also loved the Church, and delivered himself up for it; adding shortly after, This is a great sacrament, but I speak in Christ and in the Church.
>
> Whereas therefore matrimony, in the evangelical law, excels in grace, through Christ, the ancient marriages; with reason have our holy Fathers, the Councils, and the tradition of the universal Church, always taught, that it is to be numbered amongst the sacraments of the new law; against which, impious men of this age raging, have not only had false notions touching this venerable sacrament, but, introducing according to their wont, under the pretext of the Gospel, a carnal liberty, they have by word and writing asserted, not without great injury to the faithful of Christ, many things alien from the sentiment of the Catholic Church, and from the usage approved of since the times of the apostles; the holy and universal Synod wishing to meet the rashness of these men, has thought it proper, lest their pernicious contagion may draw more after it, that the more remarkable heresies and errors of the above-named schismatics be exterminated, by decreeing against the said heretics and their errors the following anathemas.
>
> **On the Sacrament of Matrimony**.
>
> - **Canon I**. If any one saith, that matrimony is not truly and properly
>   one of the seven sacraments of the evangelic law, (a sacrament)
>   instituted by Christ the Lord; but that it has been invented by men
>   in the Church; and that it does not confer grace; let him be
>   anathema.
> - **Canon II**. If any one saith, that it is lawful for Christians to have
>   several wives at the same time, and that this is not prohibited by
>   any divine law; let him be anathema.
> - **Canon III**. If any one saith, that those degrees only of consanguinity
>   and affinity, which    are set down in Leviticus, can hinder
>   matrimony from being contracted, and dissolve it when contracted; and
>   that the Church cannot dispense in some of those degrees, or
>   establish that others may hinder and dissolve it ; let him be
>   anathema.
> - **Canon IV. If any one saith, that the Church could not establish
>   impediments dissolving marriage; or that she has erred in
>   establishing them; let him be anathema.**
> - **Canon V**. *If any one saith, that on account of heresy, or irksome
>   cohabitation, or the affected absence of one of the parties, the bond
>   of matrimony may be dissolved; let him be anathema.*
> - CANON VI. If any one saith, that matrimony contracted, but not
>   consummated, is not dissolved by the solemn profession of religion by
>   one of the married parties; let him be anathema.
> - **Canon VII**. If any one saith, that the Church has erred, in that she hath taught, and >doth teach, in accordance with the evangelical and apostolical doctrine, that the bond of >matrimony cannot be dissolved on account of the adultery of one of the married parties; >and that both, or even the innocent one who gave not occasion to the adultery, cannot >contract another marriage, during the life-time of the other; and, that he is guilty of >adultery, who, having put away the adulteress, shall take another wife, as also she, who, >having put away the adulterer, shall take another husband; let him be anathema.
> - **Canon VIII**. If any one saith, that the Church errs, in that she
>   declares that, for many causes, a separation may take place between
>   husband and wife, in regard of bed, or in regard of cohabitation, for
>   a determinate or for an indeterminate period; let him be anathema.
> - **Canon IX**. If any one saith, that clerics constituted in sacred orders,
>   or Regulars, who have solemnly professed chastity, are able to
>   contract marriage, and that being contracted it is
>   valid,notwithstanding the ecclesiastical law, or vow; and that the
>   contrary is no thing else than to condemn marriage; and, that all who
>   do not feel that they have the gift of chastity, even though they
>   have made a vow thereof, may contract marriage; let him be anathema:
>   seeing that God refuses not that gift to those who ask for it
>   rightly, neither does He suffer us to be tempted above that which we
>   are able.
> - **Canon X**. If any one saith, that the marriage state is to be placed above the state of >virginity, or of celibacy, and that it is not better and more blessed to remain in >virginity, or in celibacy, than to be united in matrimony; let him be anathema.
> - **Canon XI**. If any one saith, that the prohibition of the solemnization
>   of marriages at certain times of the year, is a    tyrannical
>   superstition, derived from the superstition of the    heathen; or,
>   condemn the benedictions and other ceremonies which the    Church
>   makes use of therein; let him be anathema.
> - **Canon XII**. If any one saith, that matrimonial causes do not belong to
>   ecclesiastical judges; let him be anathema.

Comment: In which sense are you asking in your post: Can the Catholic Church err in established form of law or in a particular case?

Comment: @KenGraham The latter--I want to know if the Catholic Church has ever taught (or rather recognized) a common apologetic point one may hear from Anglicans--that medieval annullments may have often been abused. That in other words that grounds were found for an anullment that were not just. Or that in other case the inverse, that just grounds were overlooked and a marriage anullment was not granted.

Comment: Your question is one case of the question I marked as duplicate. If yours is different, please revise and show how.

Answer (score 2):

**Can the Catholic Church err on particular grounds for an anullment in a marriage?**

The Catholic Church cannot err in establishing norms for impediments for dissolving the bonds of marriage.

> Canon IV. **If any one saith, that the Church could not establish impediments dissolving marriage; or that she has erred in establishing them; let him be anathema.**

Having said that, the Catholic Church could conceivably commit an error in a particular case for the annulment in a marriage.

Once a declaration of nullity has been issued, there is no good way to contest it. However, you can appeal the decision if you believe that some information was missing or not presented fully during the investigation.

The Church allows the faithful to challenge an annulment decision, if one believes that the matrimonial tribunal has erred in its decision due to some lack of evidence during the course of its investigation.

> The Catholic Church teaches that marriage is for life. In fact, we believe that marriage is a covenantal union between a couple and God that cannot be ended by anyone — not even by God because we know that He does not go back on his covenantal agreements. So, when a relationship is so strained that you start looking into divorce and annulment, that understanding of Catholic marriage rules can be very weighty. One question we hear with regularity is whether an annulment can be contested. The answer to this is not as straightforward as it is with civil divorce proceedings. Here’s why:
>
> Understanding Annulment and Catholic Marriage Rules:
>
> In order to understand why you may not necessarily be able to contest an annulment, you first need to understand how an annulment works. The basics are these: according to Catholic marriage rules, a covenantal marriage cannot be ended by anything. And yet, an annulment decree essentially brings about an end to a marriage in a way that is recognized by the Church’s teachings. What happens during the annulment process is not a straightforward legal process of dividing assets, the way a civil divorce is. Instead, it’s an investigation to see whether all of the necessary elements for a covenantal marriage were present when vows were said. If the annulment investigation finds that even one of those necessary elements was missing, the union is not a covenantal one, and without that covenantal agreement, the marriage is nullified. Basically, without all of the necessary elements present, the Church views that marriage as never having existed.
>
> So, Can Catholic Annulments Be Contested?
>
> The annulment process is very much an investigation, and because of this, it’s very different from civil divorce proceedings. During most civil divorces, there is an opportunity for one of the spouses to disagree, whether it’s contesting how their lives are being divvied up, or protesting the divorce as a whole. During an annulment investigation, on the other hand, both spouses will have the chance to speak up and discuss their experiences, but there is not necessarily a distinct opportunity to contest the annulment process.
>
> Contesting an annulment generally comes down to disagreeing that there are grounds for the nullity of marriage to be issued, and explaining those reasons to the tribunal. However, an annulment investigation doesn’t necessarily require the participation and agreement of both spouses to proceed. You can have an annulment granted even without a word from your spouse. But, if your spouse is seeking an annulment and you want to contest it, your interview responses during the investigation are your chance to do so.
>
> **Once a declaration of nullity has been issued, there is no good way to contest it. You can appeal the decision if you believe that some information was missing or not resented fully during the investigation, but that will raise questions about why that information was not presented to begin with.**
>
> If you have questions about the annulment process, contesting an annulment, or Catholic marriage rules in general, our knowledgeable team is here to help. [Connect with Catholic Annulment - Another Chance](https://www.churchannulment.com/contact-us) to learn more about the annulment process and get compassionate guidance through the process.
>
> [Can A Catholic Annulment Be Contested?](https://www.churchannulment.com/blog/can-a-catholic-annulment-be-contested)

The Church is open to the possibility that errors could occur in the annulment process, but these errors in fact would be extremely rare to almost non-existent. The annulment process is extremely thorough and questions of both parties are exhausting to say the least.

Comment: Why is there an appeal process if the annulment is innerant?

Answer (score 1):

## Moral Certitude

Only [**moral certitude**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34959) is required to declare the nullity of a marriage.

Canonist [Raymond Leo Cardinal Burke](https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/bburke.html) (Prefect of the [Apostolic Signatura](https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/dxtas.html), the Church's "supreme court", 2008-2014) says in "The Canonical Nullity of the Marriage: Process as the Search for the Truth" (ch. 9 of [*Remaining in the Truth of Christ*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5305)), "Nature of the Process for the Declaration of Nullity of Marriage", § "2. Judgment as a Declaration regarding the Truth of a Claim of Marriage Nullity":

> The college of judges or the single judge has no power to dissolve a valid marriage, but only to search for the truth about a particular marriage and declare authoritatively either that, with [**moral certitude**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34959), the truth of the nullity of the marriage has been established or proven (*constat de nullitate*) or that such moral certitude has not been reached (*non constat de nullitate*).

> [[1983] Can. 1608](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib7-cann1501-1670_en.html#TITLE_VII._) [=[1917 can.](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7786) 1869] §1. For the pronouncement of any sentence, the judge must have **moral certitude** about the matter to be decided by the sentence.

"[Moral certitude](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34959)" is, according to Fr. John Hardon's *Modern Catholic Dictionary*:

> Confident assent concerning human conduct based on people's normal and predictable responses to certain needs, abilities, and motivations.

McHugh, O.P. & Callan, O.P., [*Moral Theology*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5547):

> 643. [Kinds of Certitude](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/35354/pg35354.html#id01330).—Judgments may be certain in a greater or less degree.
>
>           (a) They are **metaphysically certain**, when error is absolutely impossible, the opposite of what is held by the mind being a contradiction in terms which omnipotence itself could not make true. […]
>
>           (b) Judgments are **physically certain**, when error is impossible according to the laws of nature, the opposite of what is held by the mind being unrealizable except through intervention of another cause. […]
>
>           (c) Judgments are **morally certain**, when error is impossible according to what is customary among mankind, the opposite of what is held by the mind being so unlikely that it would be imprudent to be moved by it.
>      Examples: One is morally certain that what a reputedly truthful and competent person relates to one is true. A person is morally certain that a conclusion he has drawn about his duty in a particular instance is correct, if he believes that he has overlooked no means of reaching the truth. Testimony and inference, since they come from free and fallible agencies, may lead into error; but, when they appear to have the requisite qualities indicative of truth, they are for the most part reliable and in practical life have to be considered as such.

<sup>(my **emphases** throughout)
answer taken from [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89041/10672) to "[Can a declaration of nullity obtained by deception be valid?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/89039/1787)"</sup>

Comment: A very good article on moral (vs. intellectual) certitude can be found in: Réginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P., [_The Order of Things: The Realism of the Principle of Finality_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9803) ch. 6 "Moral Realism: Finality and the Formation Of Conscience".